# I'm trying to complete a table iterating in groups of data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, datatables

I know this code is wrong, but I want to know which is the correct form to do it, I'm trying to iterate the groups, and each group have 8 teams

```
    <table class="table">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <% @groups.each do |group| %>
            <th><%= group.name %></th>
          <% end %>
       </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <% @groups.each_slice(4) do |group_a, group_b, group_c, group_d| %>
          <% group_a.teams.each do |team_a|, group_b.teams.each do |team_b|, group_c.teams.each do |team_c|, group_d.teams.each do |team_d| %>
            <tr>
              <td><%= team_a.name %></td>
              <td><%= team_b.name %></td>
              <td><%= team_c.name %></td>
              <td><%= team_d.name %></td>
            </tr>
          <% end %>
       <% end %>
     </tbody>
   </table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @JagdeepSingh for your help, after try and try this is what im looking for bro:

```
`<table class="table">
  <thead class="thead-dark">
    <tr>
      <% @groups.each do |group| %>
        <th><%= group.name %></th>
      <% end %>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <% @groups.each_slice(4) do |group_a, group_b, group_c, group_d| %>
      <% for x in 0..7 do %>
        <tr>
          <td><%= group_a.teams[x].name %></td>
          <td><%= group_b.teams[x].name %></td>
          <td><%= group_c.teams[x].name %></td>
          <td><%= group_d.teams[x].name %></td>
        </tr>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>`
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution actually depends on the table structure you want to see, which you haven't clarified in the question. Here is an attempt; see how this ends up:

```
<table class="table">
  <tbody>
    <thead>
      <th>Team#1</th>
      <th>Team#2</th>
      <th>Team#3</th>
      <th>Team#4</th>
    </thead>
    <% @groups.each do |group| %>
      <tr>
        <th colspan='4'><%= group.name %></th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <% group.teams.each do |team| %>
          <td><%= team.name %></td>
        <% end %>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>
```